# regular expression is chopping off last character of filename

Tags: regex

Anyone know why this is happening:

```
Filename:     031\_Lobby.jpg

RegExp:       (\d+)\_(.*)[^\_e|\_i]\.jpg

Replacement:  \1\_\2\_i.jpg
```

That produces this:

```
031\_Lobb\_i.jpg
```

For some reason it's chopping the last character from the second back- 
reference (the "y" in "Lobby".  It *doesn't* do that when I remove the `[^_e|_i]` so I must be doing something wrong that's related to that.

Thanks!

Comment: you forgot to mention what the correct behavior should be

Answer (score 4):

You force it to chop off the last character with this part of your regex:

```
[^_e|_i]
```

Which translates as: Any single character except `"_"`, `"e"`, `"|"`, `"i"`.

The `"y"` in `"Lobby"` matches this criterion.

You *mean* `"not _e"` and `"not _i"`, obviously, but that's not the way to express it. This would be right:

```
(\d+)_(.+)(?<!_[ei])\.jpg
```

Note that the dot needs to be escaped in regular expressions.

Comment: That makes sense, but then how do I get a back-reference that returns the "Lobby" and not just the "y"?  Thanks!

Comment: The existing \2 backref should return ‘Lobby’. (?<!...) doesn't capture any actual characters. Also, the ‘.’ in ‘.jpg’ should be a literal dot ‘\.’ and not a bare dot which means ‘any character’.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  Worked like a charm, and I learned something!  Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: @bobince: That's confusing. :-) You should direct your comments with the @... style. For a while I thought you meant me with your comment.

Answer (score 1):

it is removing the "y" because [^_e|_i] matches the y, and the `.*` matches everything before the y.

Answer (score -1):

You're forcing it to have a last character different from _e and _i. You should use this instead (note the last *):

```
(\d+)_(.*)[^_e|_i]*.jpg
```